# Is it possible to adapt round HVAC diffusers to square?

Tags: hvac, ducts, central-air

I am working on a remodel in my older home. Currently all of the HVAC is run through sheet metal ceiling ducts, most of which are 8" diameter, and then when they reach the rooms, flair out to a 10" opening with a round metal diffuser and damper. I do not like the look of these round diffusers, but am having trouble finding a similar product with a square diffuser that I can install on these openings. Most of the products I'm finding are for new installs and I don't think can be fitted easily.

The ceiling opening is just under 10" and behind the sheet rock is some sort of sheet metal flange. The existing diffusers just screw into the ceiling and the into the sheet metal behind the sheet rock.

Has anyone successfully converted from round registers to square?

[image: 10 inch ceiling opening]

[image: Back of damper and diffuser]

[image: Front of damper and diffuser]

Answer (score 4):

Easily won't happen here.

If you want to waste **considerable effort and money** on what appears to be a minor aesthetic change, you can do this. It will involve ripping into the ceiling to install round to square adapters on the existing ducts.

If you want a square grille that fits the round opening you have directly, you're probably out of luck, unless you box it down from the ceiling. That seems *far uglier* to me, but perhaps ypu'd like it. There's no room for the damper in a square grille to work if it's screwed onto a round opening.